# what is the connection string for this database

Tags: sql-server

I have a database called `MyDatabase` exists in `sql server 2008 r2` on `windows server 2003`

I want to test my website on that server using `Windows Authentication`

#### My Question

what is the connection string

#### I think that

> connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>

But I don't know if it is correct. Also, I can't try because I have to give the code to my manager, I need to be everything perfect when I gave them.

#### i am using .net framework 4

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @meziantou thanks for your suggestions, I have read that website before and I want to be sure that what I have understood, which is the code I have shown, is correct. Please help

Comment: @user3432257 So why not jus t try it out? This is a trivial thing to check - checking is faster than even writing this post here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that by going to Tools->Connect to Database

[image]

In the Add Connection dialog you'll have your server name and your db name (or add it) and click the **Advanced** button

[image]

In the Advanced Properties dialog copy the string marked below:

[image]

This will be your string, in this case:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("DataSource=MCA\\LENOVO;Initial  Catalog=DecryptTesting;Integrated Security=True");
```

Make sure you add one more slash "\" like above or an "@" to a connection. You need to escape the backward slash \ in your connection string or use the "@" symbol if you want to avoid escaping characters in your string:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"DataSource=MCA\LENOVO;Initial Catalog=DecryptTesting;Integrated Security=True");
```

EDIT: DataSource is the name of your server, Initial Catalog is your database

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, could you check my new question pleaes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578638/sql-server-2008-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-network-service